# Posting to managed page using Drupal for Facebook not working

Tags: social-network

I am able to post to my feed but not to a page that I manage. I can select it from the drop down menu when creating a new node but I get the following error message:

> Failed to query https://graph.facebook.com/131180330289436/feed. Forbidden: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action OAuthException 200 (http 403)
>   Failed to query https://graph.facebook.com/131180330289436/feed.
>
> ```
> Array (
>   [method] => POST
>   [data] => access_token=mytoken&message=&link=http%3A//mysite.com/node/577&name=Honey&description=Honey&actions=%7B%22name%22%3A%22View%20More%22%2C%22link%22%3A%22http%3A%5C/%5C/mysite.com%5C/node%5C/577%22%7D
> )
> ```
>
> Forbidden: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action OAuthException 200 (http 403)
>   Could not post Honey to facebook. You might avoid this error in the future by granting additional permissions.
>   Post Honey to facebook failed with this error: Forbidden: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action OAuthException 200 (http 403)

As in the documentation, I've tried applying for the 'manage_pages' permission but they have stated that it is only necessary for public apps.